# Tengo problemas al relacionar dos Modelos en nodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estos son los modelos que deseo relacionar [image: Modelos y Controlador]

el usuario.js es el modelo que deseo realcionar con el category, en el codigo de category se puede ver a usuario referenciado pero al momento de imprimirlo o retornarlo en el controlador me lo manda como undefine,
Saben a que se deba esto?

[image: Peticion post]

dentro de los headers estoy enviando un token ya que sin el no deja modificar la data

[image: este es el error que me da la consola]

Comment: En el esquema de usuario esta cambiando _id por uid. Entonces cuando llama a _id en category.js (línea 18) ese atributo no existe. Debería llamarlo como: req.usuario.uid

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!